# how prototype properties are delegated to sub class from super class in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

Please help me to understand following code snippet.

```
var ob = {a:20,b:30};
Object.prototype.c = '40';
for (var x in ob){
    console.log(x); // will log a,b,c in console
}
var keys = Object.keys(ob) ;
console.log(keys); // will log a,b in console
```

My question is that , How putting property 'c' on the prototype of 'Object' will make it available to 'ob' ?

Edit: Basically I want to know which default constructor function is called when we try to create an object and what are the basic responsibilities performed by the constructor ?

Comment: The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's **own enumerable** properties -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: ok , Thanks, But I want to know, when ob is created, except its own enumerable property , what else properties (if any, pls correct me) is provided to object 'ob' ?

Comment: @Anant: Check the docs, there are [lots of them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)

Comment: @Bergi ,sure, will have a look , thanks for the useful link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object literal (`{}`) will inherit from `Object.prototype`.
`Object.prototype.c = '40';` sets the `c` property on `Object`'s prototype, so all objects inheriting from `Object` will be able to access this property. Any properties defined on `Object`'s prototype will be accessible on objects inheriting from it.

The difference between `for (var x in ob)` and `Object.keys(ob)` is that `Object.keys(ob)` will return only the properties of the `ob` object, whereas `for (var x in ob)` will traverse the prototype chain and find the `c` property on `Object`'s prototype.

By default, no properties defined on `Object`'s prototype will be included in a for-in loop as they are not enumerable. An added property is enumerable by default.

Comment: Did you really mean to say that no properties are available on `Object.prototype`? What about [all of these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) then?

Comment: No, I meant to say properties that will be included in a for-in loop. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ah, you meant "enumerable" not "accessible". That would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The *Object.keys()* method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, the difference being that a *for-in* loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well, so `Object.keys(ob)` will enumerate only ob own property not the property of ob prototype

**[Object Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)**

> `Object.prototype.constructor` **-->** Specifies the function that creates an
>   object's prototype.
>
> `Object.prototype.__proto__`  **-->** Points to the object
>   which was used as prototype when the object was instantiated.
>
> `Object.prototype.__noSuchMethod__` **-->** Allows a function to be defined
>   that will be executed when an undefined object member is called as a
>   method.

Comment: thanks for the answer, So as you said, the 'Constructor' for every object is 'Object.prototype.constructor', and it create an internal prototype object for every object, and put the reference to prototype object into 'proto' property ? right ? what else is done by  'Object.prototype.constructor' ?

Comment: the prototype.contructor returns a reference to the Object function that created the instance's prototype.

Comment: @Anant: All objects that inherit from `Object.prototype` will have their inherited `.constructor` property point to `Object` - unless it was overwritten somewhere in the prototype chain (which is the default for objects created with custom constructors).

Comment: @Infer-On: Why did you quote only these 3 properties? And 2 of them non-standard even?

Comment: Note that 2 of the above 3 properties are JavaScript™ methods and are not part of the ECMAScript standard.

Comment: @Bergi I mentioned only properties, excluded those marked as obsolete

Comment: @Infer-On: …and those whose values happen to be functions. "properties" does refer to "methods" as well in JavaScript.